# Is there a way to copy the firmware (BIOS) that came with my PC onto a USB flash drive?

Tags: bios, firmware

I bought a new Lenovo Legion 5 PC. It comes with Windows preinstalled. I was wondering is there a way to copy the firmware that comes with the PC onto a USB flash drive without having to download it off the website?

For instance if I wanted to copy the firmware of the BIOS to reinstall it at a later time.

Let’s say it got infected with a rootkit. Am I able to just make copies of all the firmware from the PC in case it gets infected to later reflash with out having to get it off the Lenovo website?

Answer (score 1):

There *might* be tools that allow you to dump the original BIOS. Sometimes the official tools come with a (hidden) option to make a backup before updating the BIOS.

But running those on an already compromised machine could not be reliable. The best way, but more complicated and risky, is to use an SPI programmer and dump the BIOS chip through hardware.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.